# Filling up cell based on another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I fill in the blank cells on the first table based on the next 2?

| code | Product | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a |  |
| 4 | a |  |
| 5 | b |  |

| code | Product | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | X1 |
| 2 | a | X1 |
| 3 | a | X2 |
| 4 | a | X2 |
| 5 | a | X3 |

| code | Product | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | Z1 |
| 2 | b | Z1 |
| 3 | b | Z2 |
| 4 | b | Z2 |
| 5 | b | Z3 |

Comment: I can't see the logic in your tables, please explain what exactly should be done.

Comment: Table nr 2 and nr 3 have values in the "Key" column. I want to fill in the cells under "Key" on table nr 1 based on a combo of code and product. I want excel to fill in X1 under "Key" on the first cell on table nr 1 because "code" 1 and "Product" a have "Key" X1. Just noticed that my question had a text error.

Comment: Are tables 2 and 3 exactly the same layout, just different data? Can you combine them into one, either as they are, or using something like Power Query to append them together? Add a column using a formula, or again through PQ to concatenate Product & Code then use this in a really simple lookup formula such as index/match.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the IF() function.
If the tables are really "smart tables" (please see **[Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)**) named `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`, then the formula is quite simple

```
=IF([@Product]="a";
  INDEX(Table2[Key];MATCH([@code];Table2[code];0));
  INDEX(Table3[Key];MATCH([@code];Table3 [code];0)))
```